# How can I set my connection up to my used as a proxy?

Tags: windows-7, proxy, internet-connection

As the title says, I want to be able to use my internet connection as a SOCKS (or some other type of proxy?) from another device and connection. What is the easiest way to go about this?

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: An Internet connection is used by a Proxy Server, but you still need a "Server". Please describe your network, and where all the clients are in relation to your proposed proxy box.

Comment: There are a number of windows-based proxy products (even free ones) you could use for this.  Just run a proxy on your computer, and allow it to be accessed from the internet.  You will need to lock it down so that not just anyone can use it, otherwise it will soon be discovered by port scanners and your IP will end up in a list of open proxies, and you'll find lots of people surfing through you (and doing less savoury things) chewing all your bandwidth and probably getting you into trouble with your ISP if not law enforcement.